# Use of uninitialized value in join or string at

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = "/";
my @old = `ls -1rtA $dir`;
#print @old;
my #variable declaration
while(1){
        $oldlen = scalar @old;
        @new = `ls -1rtA $dir`;
        print @new;
        $newlen = scalar @new;
        if(@old ~~ @new)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $diff=$oldlen+1;
            print "$diff \n";
            print "$list \n";
            #print "@new[$list] \n";
            #$op=$new[$list];
            print "$newlen \n";
            #pop @core,$op;
            print "@new[$diff..$newlen]";
            print @core;
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

Use of uninitialized value in join or string at `print "@new[$diff..$newlen]";`

What is causing this issue?

What does the error mean?

Comment: @ysth stupid reaction

Comment: First thing to check is the value of $diff and $newlen compared with the size of `@new`.

Comment: @ikegami How to do that? please add a code...

Comment: @ikegami if i put the value it is working fine, if i pass it has variable it throws same error...

Comment: The code as presented doesn't even compile.  Try removing your commented out lines and paring it down to just code that generates the error you're asking about.

Comment: You know, I had a similar issue, and this question helped, so I marked it up.  Although it could have been written better, I found it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `$newlen` to the number of elements in the array `@new` and then tried to access `$new[$newlen]`. The elements of `@new` are at indices `0` to `$newlen - 1`, so `$new[$newlen]` is beyond the end of the array. You get the warning because this evaluates to `undef` and is uninitialised.

You have the same problem with the start index of the slice, which should read

```
print "@new[$oldlen..$newlen-1]"
```